# Insert ajax data to database based on model

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I use ajax form data and get these data:

```
model[lat]:39.5500507
model[lng]:-105.78206740000002
model[width]:100
model[widthIn]:%
model[height]:300
model[mapTypeId]:ROADMAP
model[zoom]:15
```

I use wordpress in the server side. All I want to do is to insert them into database using `$wpdb` all in once like:

```
$modeldata = $_POST["something that represents whole model data"]
```

And then insert an array like:

```
array($modeldata -> $modeldata)
```

So each model data will be placed into their respective column with the same name in database. For example, `model[width]` in column `width`, `model[height]` in column `height`.

Is something like that possible instead of inserting them one by one?

NOTE: I have created all the columns name in table so don't assume I haven't

Comment: better to hook the ajax request via [wp_ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) or [wp_ajax_nopriv](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post data is as follows

```
$_POST = array(

   'model' => array(
        'lat' => 39.00
        'lng' => 105.00
        'width' => 
        'widthIn' => %
        ---
   );
);
```

So in wordpress, to insert these data in say 'geotable' table, use following code block

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert('geotable',$_POST['model']);
```

Comment: Your code doesnt work, is it a must to use `wp_localize_script`?